# How to get total of parameters on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have user model, and each user have model name "voucher"

and voucher has "visited"

```
user has_many :voucher
voucher has_many :visited
```

My question is how to get total of visited from the user.

I tried `<%= @user.vouchers.visited.count %>` but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean `Visit` and not `Visited` which is not a good model name as its not a noun (models represent things, not states).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work as `voucher` is a relationship and the `visisted` relationship is only on the instance.

```rb
@user.vouchers.first.visited
```

You could introduce a 'has many through' relationship on user like

```rb
class User
  has_many :voucher
  has_many :visited_voucher, through: :voucher
end

user.visited_voucher.count
```

If you don't want to introduce another relationship then you could just craft a query in your controller like

```rb
visited_voucher_count = Visit.where(
  voucher_id: user.voucher
).count
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

```
#user.rb
has_many :vouchers
has_many :visited, through: :vouchers

#vouchers
has_many :visited
```

To get total number of `visited` objects under user, call
user.visited

Comment: i got error uninitialized constant User::visited

Comment: @GarbelaGarbela can you post the models having associations specified as an update?